# If $|\phi| \approx |\psi|$, then Is $|| \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\phi \hat{f}] ||_p \leq C || \mathcal{F}^{-1} [\psi \hat{f}] ||_p$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

$\underline{\textbf{Background:}}$

I am currently trying to estimate the following $L^p$ norm:

\begin{align}
& \Big{|}\Big{|} A \Big{|}\Big{|}_p \\
& =
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Big{|} \int_{|\xi|<2t^{1/2}} 
\exp\Big{(} ix\cdot\xi  \Big{)}
\Big{(}1 - i \sqrt{\frac{4t}{|\xi|^2} -1 } \Big{)} \exp\Big{(}-\frac{|\xi|^2}{2} \big{(}1+i\sqrt{ \frac{4t}{|\xi|^2} -1  }\big{)}\Big{)} \text{d}\xi \Big{|}^p \text{d}x  \Big{\} }^{1/p} ,
\end{align}

where $t > 0$, and $d \geq 2$.

The above complicated function was obtained from part of an inverse Fourier transform (which needs to be split into small and large $|\xi|$, as the $\sqrt{\frac{4t}{|\xi|^2} - 1}$ part blows up at $|\xi| = 2t^{1/2}$).

As such, I would like to treat it as a Fourier transform still (formally), by rewriting as

\begin{align}
\Big{|}\Big{|} A \Big{|}\Big{|}_p = \Big{|}\Big{|} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big{[} \exp\Big{(}i t^{1/2} |\xi|^2 \sqrt{ \frac{4}{|\xi|^2} -1  }\Big{)}  \hat{f} \Big{]}  \Big{|}\Big{|}_p ,
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
\hat{f}(t,\xi) := \Big{(}1 - i \sqrt{\frac{4t}{|\xi|^2} -1 } \Big{)} \exp\Big{(}-\frac{|\xi|^2}{2} \Big{)}\Bigg{|}_{|\xi|<2t^{1/2}}
\end{align}

(I hope to get around the issue of smoothness by taking the limit of $\hat{f}$ times some test function.)

$\underline{\textbf{Problem:}}$

I would like to simplify the problem further. Note that the multiplier in $\hat{f}$ is pointwise bounded above and below:

\begin{align}
C^{-1} \frac{t^{1/2}}{|\xi|} \leq  \Big{|}1 - i \sqrt{\frac{4t}{|\xi|^2} -1 } \Big{|} \leq C \frac{t^{1/2}}{|\xi|}, \text{ for all } C \geq 4.
\end{align}

I am wondering if this permits the following estimate:

\begin{align}
& \Big{|}\Big{|} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big{[} \exp\Big{(}i t^{1/2} |\xi|^2 \sqrt{ \frac{4}{|\xi|^2} -1  }\Big{)}  \hat{f} \Big{]}  \Big{|}\Big{|}_p \\
& \leq 
C
\Big{|}\Big{|} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\Big{[}   \exp\Big{(}i t^{1/2} |\xi|^2 \sqrt{ \frac{4}{|\xi|^2} -1  }\Big{)}  \frac{t^{1/2}}{|\xi|} \exp\Big{(}-\frac{|\xi|^2}{2} \Big{)}  \Big{]}  \Big{|}\Big{|}_p.
\end{align}

In more general terms, if we have pointwise boundedness above and below for a Fourier multiplier

\begin{align}
C^{-1}\psi(\xi) \leq \phi(\xi) \leq C\psi(\xi), \text{ for all } \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d,
\end{align}

can we then say

\begin{align}
\Big{|}\Big{|} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \Big{[} \phi \hat{g} \Big{]} \Big{|}\Big{|}_p \leq C \Big{|}\Big{|} \mathcal{F}^{-1} \Big{[} \psi \hat{g} \Big{]} \Big{|}\Big{|}_p,
\end{align}

for sufficiently well behaved $\hat{g}, \phi, \psi$?

\begin{align}
\end{align}

Comment: As for your last question, I'm pretty sure the answer is no. Boundedness of multipliers in $L^p$ for $p\neq 2$ has to do with more than just size of the function (see for instance the Mikhlin multiplier theorem and its generalizations).